# gdb: Program exited with code 030000000375

Tags: c, gdb, mingw, stack-overflow, segmentation-fault

I am teaching myself to use gdb and am running some random tests.  It may be worth mentioning that I am using a portable installation of MinGW on Windows 7 x64.  I've created a program which I know results in a stack overflow, and as I run through it in gdb I first get two SIGSEGV signals (no surprise), and then it exits (again no surprise) with code 030000000375.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
Program exited with code 030000000375.
```

Curiosity getting the best of me... what the heck is that code?  I googled it and found very little.

Thanks!

UPDATE: For reference I tried the same program on Ubuntu, and the results are slightly different:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
The program no longer exists.
```

Comment: Do you always get the same code? If so, have you tried changing the data of your program and seeing if you still get the same code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`gdb` prints out the exit code in octal format. Not obvious, but indicated by the leading `0`.

So `030000000375` is `0xC00000FD` in hex, which makes the code look much more common to a windows programmer.

`0xC00000FD` is `STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW` and should be defined in `ntstatus.h`.

Comment: Good find, thanks!  And very interesting that Windows actually tells you when you get a stack overflow, but linux does not.

Comment: You are welcome! Btw: Perhaps you should modify the topic of this question to "*gdb: **Program** exited with code 030000000375*" as it's not `gdb` exiting with this code. @The111

Comment: Done.  And to answer your other question in the comments, the test program I was using is one I came up with long ago in this post where I inadvertently taught myself about the existence of stack overflows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611198/understanding-memory-allocation-test-program-crashing