# Unknown Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped) in multithread initialization

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, semaphore

I've had three different lab TAs look at my code and none of them have been able to help me, so I've decided to try here. Unless I delete all code relating to both gettimeofday and any semaphores, I get a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)​" error. I've boiled down my code to only the main thread with simple declarations to attempt to get to the root of the problem.

My code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/time.h>  

void *threadN (void *); /* thread routines */

pthread_t tid[1]; /* array of thread IDs */

int main() 
{
    int i,j;
   /* here create and initialize all semaphores */ 
   int mutex = sem_create(777777, 1);

   int MatrixA[6000][3000];

   for (i=0; i < 6000; i++) {
       for (j=0; j < 3000; j++) {
           MatrixA[i][j]=i*j;
       }
   }
   int MatrixB[3000][1000];

   for (i=0; i < 3000; i++) {
       for (j=0; j < 1000; j++) {
           MatrixB[i][j]=i*j;
       }
   }

   int MatrixC[6000][1000];
   struct timeval tim;
   gettimeofday(&tim, NULL);
   float t1=tim.tv_sec+(tim.tv_usec/1000000.0);  
   gettimeofday(&tim, NULL);  
   float t2=tim.tv_sec+(tim.tv_usec/1000000.0);  
   printf("%.2lf seconds elapsed\n", t2-t1); 

   sem_rm(sem_open(777777, 1));
   return 0;
}​
```

I'm completely stumped here.

Comment: Can you please post an explanation of what your code is attempting to do? What are the expected outputs when you input certain values? Without this information it is difficult to debug your question.

Comment: At this point the code doesn't do much of anything. This is only the beginning o what will eventually use multithreading to quickly assign values to an array, but before I reach that point I need this first section to be able to run without simply giving a segmentation fault and nothing else.

Comment: In that case, can you narrow down exactly which line your seg fault is being thrown from. Threading in C is a notoriously tricky business.

Comment: The fault doesn't happen so long as I delete the gettimeofday functions, the float declarations, and the semaphores. If any of them are left in I get the fault.

Comment: The code crashes in which line?

Comment: You are using `l` as size modifier in `printf("%.2lf....)` which is not correct. Maybe you wanted `L` for `long double` but your variables are just `float`s. Otherwise I got 0.00 with `float`s and correct output if I change `t1` and `t2` do `double` using `printf("%2f...)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding memory allocation, test program crashing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611198/understanding-memory-allocation-test-program-crashing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You eat your stack. See [Radix sort for 10^6 array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29362119/radix-sort-for-106-array-in-c), comment from @Joachim Pileborg:

*Local variables are usually stored on the stack, and the stack is usually limited to single-digit megabytes. On Windows for example, the default is 1MB per process, on Linux the default is 8MB...*

I tried your code on Windows and it was dead with just `MatrixA` defined: 6000*3000*4 (for int)...

So you will have to move matrix data out of stack: define matrix as static or allocate on heap.

Answer (score 1):

A useful thing I have found for tracking seg faults is with using gdb.

```
gcc -g -o a.out -c program.c
```

-g generates source level debug information

```
gdb a.out core
```

this starts up gdb with a.out

```
(gdb) run
```

this should run the program and show the line where the seg fault is happening.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. It would have suited as comment however ...

Comment: GDB answers all C debug questions!
OP if GDB does not work for you I suggest running "man sem_open" we may have different versions but the first argument for sem_open is a char * so if it sem_open is looking at address location 777777 it would be a source for a potential seg fault.