# Radix sort for 10^6 array in C

Tags: c, radix-sort

i have this code and it crash in the middle of processing. System gives message "filename.exe stopped working. What is wrong here? 
I declare array as global to be able to have so big number of elements, but still it doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 1000000
#define SHOWPASS

void print(int *a, int n) {
 int i;
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  printf("%d\t", a[i]);
}

void radix_sort(int *a, int n) {
 int i, b[MAX], m = 0, exp = 1;
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  if (a[i] > m)
   m = a[i];
 }

 while (m / exp > 0) {
  int box[10] = { 0 };
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
   box[a[i] / exp % 10]++;
  for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
   box[i] += box[i - 1];
  for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   b[--box[a[i] / exp % 10]] = a[i];
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
   a[i] = b[i];
  exp *= 10;

#ifdef SHOWPASS
  printf("\n\nPASS   : ");
  print(a, n);
#endif
 }
}
int arr[MAX];
int main() {
 //int arr[MAX];
 int i, num;

 printf("\nEnter total elements (num < %d) : ", MAX);
 scanf("%d", &num);

 printf("\ncreate array : ");
 for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
  arr[i]=rand()%10;

 printf("\nARRAY  : ");
 print(&arr[0], num);

 radix_sort(&arr[0], num);

 printf("\n\nSORTED  : ");
 print(&arr[0], num);

 return 0;
}
```

Here is another code i tried, this time i used malloc. But still it crashes before starting sort. everything is fine if number of elements is <100000.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 1000000
#define SHOWPASS

void print(int *a, int n) {
 int i;
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  printf("%d\t", a[i]);
}

void radix_sort(int *a, int n) {
 int i, b[MAX], m = 0, exp = 1;
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  if (a[i] > m)
   m = a[i];
 }

 while (m / exp > 0) {
  int box[10] = { 0 };
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
   box[a[i] / exp % 10]++;
  for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
   box[i] += box[i - 1];
  for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   b[--box[a[i] / exp % 10]] = a[i];
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
   a[i] = b[i];
  exp *= 10;

#ifdef SHOWPASS
  printf("\n\nPASS   : ");
  print(a, n);
#endif
 }
}

int i, num;
int main() {

int* arr = (int*)malloc(MAX * sizeof(int));
int i;

 printf("\ncreate array : ");
 for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
  arr[i]=rand()%10;

 printf("\nARRAY  : ");
 print(&arr[0], MAX);

 radix_sort(&arr[0], MAX);

 printf("\n\nSORTED  : ");
 print(&arr[0], MAX);
free(arr);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Local variables are usually stored on the stack, and the stack is usually limited to single-digit megabytes. On Windows for example, the default is 1MB per process, on Linux the default is 8MB.  You use 4000000 bytes for the array `b` in the `radix_sort` function, so if you're on Windows you're over the limit there.

Comment: On an unrelated note, array decays to pointers to their first element, for example when passed to functions. So `&arr[0]` is no different from `arr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is here:

```
 int i, b[MAX], m = 0, exp = 1;
```

Allocating a huge (1 million `int`) array on the stack is not possible on some if not most systems.

You should `malloc` the temporary array and allocate only the size needed for the sort, namely `n * sizeof(int)`.

Another problem is this: your `radix_sort` cannot handle negative numbers.

Less important but worth mentioning: your implementation is not stable. Not a problem for simple `int` arrays, but potentially incorrect for larger structures.

Furthermore, your code is inefficient: you use division and modulo 10.  It would be much faster to use shifting and masking.

Here is a more efficient implementation for large arrays:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void radix_sort(int *a, size_t size) {
    size_t counts[sizeof(*a)][256] = {{ 0 }}, *cp;
    size_t n, i, sum;
    unsigned int *tmp, *src, *dst, *aa;

    dst = tmp = malloc(size * sizeof(*a));
    src = (unsigned int *)a;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        unsigned int v = src[i] + (unsigned int)INT_MIN;
        for (n = 0; n < sizeof(*a) * 8; n += 8)
            counts[n >> 3][(v >> n) & 255]++;
    }
    for (n = 0; n < sizeof(*a) * 8; n += 8) {
        cp = &counts[n >> 3][0];
        if (cp[0] == size) continue;
        for (i = sum = 0; i < 256; i++)
            cp[i] = (sum += cp[i]) - cp[i];
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            dst[cp[((src[i] + (unsigned int)INT_MIN) >> n) & 255]++] = src[i];
        aa = src;
        src = dst;
        dst = aa;
    }
    if (src == tmp) {
        memcpy(a, src, size * sizeof(*a));
    }
    free(tmp);
}
```

Comment: 6 errors and 6 warnings in this function.

Comment: Your first tip where bug is helped me :) Thanks

Comment: @rimasbimas: I added the missing `#include <stdlib.h>` and a couple of `{}`.  Can you tell me which compiler you use and what errors and warnings you get?